# Adding text to web browser document redirects to about:blank

Tags: vb.net, browser

When I load a page into the web-browser control I have a text box and a button to insert more html and various other, but when I do so it redirects to about:blank. How do I stop this from happening. I cannot find anything that would hint me to fixing this problem anywhere

Also this is how I add text to the page:

```
wbChat.DocumentText += Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you `Text` a variable ?

I have tried testing it by using the following code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("c:\test.html")

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText += TextBox1.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

And the test.html file contains the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>All contents are displayed below</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I tried typing something on the TextBox and clicked the button, it was appended to the end of webpage.

Comment: Now might be a bad time to mention I'm using the Webkit wrapper for .NET